# Bash completion for `unrar`

Tags: bash, autocomplete, rar

When `bash-completion` is loaded, `unrar x` completes after pressing tab to RAR-archives in the directory.

But for multipart archives with the new naming convention, like

> Filename.part01.rar 
>   Filename.part02.rar 
>   Filename.part03.rar

it doesn't see any difference between the first archive ending on `.part1.rar`, `.part01.rar` or `.part001.rar` and all the others parts like `.part02.rar` which are never opened directly, it completes them *all*.

Is it possible to configure bash-completion so that only the *first part* of multipart RAR-archives is completed? This means files which end on `.rar` but must not end on `.part□.rar` where □ is a number greater than 1 with leading zeros (e.g. 2 or 02 or 002)?

**The following works for me. I DO NOT know if this is 100% correct:**

```
# unrar(1) completion                                      -*- shell-script -*-

_unrar()
{
    local cur prev words cword cmp_opts=1 i
    _init_completion || return

    # Check if all of the middle part are options.
    # If not, we break at the last-option idx, and won't complete opts.
    for ((i=1; i<${#words[@]}-1; i++)); do
        # not using the whole list for checking -- too verbose
        if [[ ${words[i]} != -* || ${words[i]} == '--' ]]; then
            cmp_opts=0
            break
        fi
    done

    if [[ $cur == -* ]] && ((cmp_opts)); then   # options
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '-ad -ap -av- -c- -cfg- -cl -cu -dh -ep -f
            -idp -ierr -inul -kb -o+ -o- -ow -p -p- -r -ta -tb -tn -to -u -v
            -ver -vp -x -x@ -y' -- "$cur" ) )
    elif ((cword == 1)); then                   # command
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'e l lb lt p t v vb vt x' -- "$cur" ) )
    elif ((cword == i+1)); then                 # archive
        _filedir '[rR][aA][rR]'
        # If there is a second, third, ... ninth part
        for i in "${COMPREPLY[@]}"; do
            if [[ $i == *.part*(0)[2-9].[rR][aA][rR] ]]; then
                # Only look for the first, since it's the only useful one
                COMPREPLY=()
                _filedir 'part*(0)1.[rR][aA][rR]'
                break
            fi
        done
    else                                        # files.../path...
        _filedir
    fi

} &&
complete -F _unrar unrar

# ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
```

Comment: Bash completion settings are stored at `/etc/bash_completion.d/` with one file per command. I am not fully familiar with the synthax, but maybe you'll have an idea by looking at it?

Comment: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/unrar (not complete)

Comment: Wait a sec. Let me address the part issue too…

Comment: All done (seemingly) at https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/pull/12. Bypassed all the number parsing with some tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/pull/12/files to get a sense of how this filtering can be done.

Basically you will need to post-process `COMPREPLY[]` in some ways to get rid of the mis-completions. You can add a wrapper around too:

```
_mycomp_unrar(){
    local i
    _unrar "${[@]}" # use the old one
    # now copy the for i in "${COMPREPLY[]}" stuff
} &&
complete -p rar           # remove old completion
complete -F _mycomp_unrar # use your good new one
```

Or you can send a Pull Request (as shown above) and see what happens.

---

Added commit https://github.com/Arthur2e5/bash-completion-1/commit/a586ede to fix the problem that the existance of parts will stop normal files from showing up. (The glob as a whole is.. unreadable.)

Now you need to copy the `if ((cmp_parts))` part too. Also, make `cmp_parts` local.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly it does not work. I've made two small changes to your code (see the edit to my question). Now it works for me. But I can barely program in bash, so I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: @viuser That change is a nice one. Yeah, I forgot to clear the array and a `$`.

Comment: @viuser You may want to check out the new commit.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Your code is kind of messy, but it has worked so far.